How to import data from excel sheets using djaango project
import os
import django
import pandas as pd

# Set up Django environment
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'jobportal.settings')
django.setup()

from jobs.models import Job  

excel_file = r"D:\Job Portal\jobportal\JobsData.xlsx"

data = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    job = Job(
        title=row['title'],
        company = row['company'],
        job_type=row['job_type'],
        skills_required=row['skills_required'],
        description=row['description'],
        location=row['location'],
        date_posted=row['date_posted'],  
        experience_required=row.get('experience_required', None)  
    )
    job.save()

print("Data successfully inserted!")


to fill database data from excel but it gave me no module name No module named 'jobportal'
I want this code takes jobdata excel file and upload my mysql database in django job model

where do you run the interpreter. Is there a directory named jobportal in the pwd?

But I would here avise to work with a Django management command.

It looks like you run the interpreter in a directory where there is nu subdirectory jobportal, so it can not import that.
I would however advise to make this a management command [Django-doc], which is typically easier to maintain, and also is called just like any other command.
So we can wrap it in a command with:
# some_app/management/commands/import_excel.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from jobs.models import Job
import pandas as pd

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Import Excel data'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('files', nargs='+')

    def handle(self, *args, files=(), **kwargs):
        for excel_file in files:
            data = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

            for index, row in data.iterrows():
                job = Job(
                    title=row['title'],
                    company=row['company'],
                    job_type=row['job_type'],
                    skills_required=row['skills_required'],
                    description=row['description'],
                    location=row['location'],
                    date_posted=row['date_posted'],
                    experience_required=row.get('experience_required', None),
                )
                job.save()

        print('Data successfully inserted!')
and then run the command with manage.py
python3 manage.py import_excel 'D:\Job Portal\jobportal\JobsData.xlsx' --settings=jobportal.settings
You can here even list multiple excel files that will then all be imported.
